# Get inputs from text file and delete lines in another text file according to the inputs

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file (name.txt) with following format:

```
aaaaaaaa 1245
bbbbbbbb,456
1.2.3.4 nnnnnnnn
cccccccc
```

Another text file (cleanup.txt) contains names that i need to remove:

```
aaaaaaaa
nnnnnnnn
```

How to using batch file to delete some lines in name.txt according to cleanup.txt and create a new file new_name.txt?

new_name.txt

```
bbbbbbbb,456
cccccccc
```

What i am doing now is to manually edit the batch file command

```
type name.txt | findstr /v aaaaaaaa | findstr /v nnnnnnnn > new_name.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a basic command like this:

```dos
FindStr/VG:"cleanup.txt" "name.txt">"new_name.txt"
```

Comment: But this will having problem such as delete all lines have that string. I have servers name such as HAIM, HAIM1,HAIM2, if i use HAIM in the cleanup.txt, the rest two will be deleted as well. How to delete the exact match?

Comment: i think i figured it out using FindStr /I /X /V /G:"cleanup.txt" "name.txt">"new_name.txt"

Comment: Of course those additional switches would help in that scenario, but you need to understand that we could only provide a response based upon the information available at the time of answering. Had you provided the information "I have servers....." and changed the format of `name.txt` to the same as `cleanup.txt` we could have answered you a week ago. It's a little unfair to respond to my answer with additional information after a week and not give me sufficient time to respond. Your `cleanup.txt` matches would probably be better in this format though, so that it matches full words, `\<HAIM1\>`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with using command **FINDSTR** as posted already by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo).

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /G:"cleanup.txt" "name.txt" >"new_name.txt"
```

**FINDSTR** searches in each line of `name.txt` for any string listed in `cleanup.txt` and would output the line from `name.txt` on a positive match.

But output are the lines from `name.txt` **NOT** containing a string listed in `cleanup.txt` because of option `/V` which inverts the output.

The output of **FINDSTR** is redirected to file `new_name.txt`.

You might add the switch `/B` to get written into file `new_name.txt` only the lines **NOT** containing any string in `cleanup.txt` **at begin** of a line in `name.txt`.

Open a command prompt window and run `findstr /?` for more information on options of **FINDSTR**.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).